# Excel Performance issues with countif on multiple rows

Tags: excel

I have a large XLS with ~70K rows.  I download a refreshed version of this file each day and extract those where the '[area]=WE', the are which I am responsible for.  This part is straight forward.
There are however some cases in which I will need to also include some records from areas that other people are responsible for.

I have two columns that extract a segment of the [Customer Name] upto the first space.  The first column does it for records where '[Area]=WE', or puts 'N/A' as the value.  The second column does this the other way around. `TRIM(LEFT(F66338,IFERROR(FIND(" ",F66338),LEN(F66338))))`

In a third column I have tried to do a `countif`, searching the entire first column of data for the value in the second column (single cell) `COUNTIF($BG$12:$BG$66742,BH8)`.
Whilst it works, it takes a long time to calculate it, incrementing 'Calculating x%' by 1% every other second.

EDIT: For each entry (that is not 'N/A') in the second column, I want to know if there is at least one instance of it in the first column. I do not need to know how many.

Is there a quicker way to perform the countif?

Comment: Are you running the countif to count the occurrences of BH8 into BG12:BG66742 or only to check if there is at least one 1 BH8 into the column?

Comment: Updated the article.  I only need to know IF there is at least one in the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only need to check for at least one occurrence, a slightly faster way would be to use `=MATCH()`:

```
=MATCH(BH8, $BG$12:$BG$66742, 0)
```

Will return `#N/A!` for values not found and a number for those found (the number of rows as from cell BG12).

As soon as a match is found, the formula terminates, whereas `COUNTIF` will continue until it reaches the end to look for more (if any) matching values.

Otherwise, I don't know anything faster than that, except maybe using `VLOOKUP` which I believe should be either on par or slightly slower.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst using `MATCH()` was marginally quicker, it still took almost the same time.

I've now created a Pivot Table in a separate tab based on the first column (Dynamic Range), the `match()` now references this pivot table rather than the main table column, which means it calculates in <10 seconds.

As there are many duplicate values in this column, this works well in this particular instance.

Comment: +1 Yes, that works too! I was wondering though if the time to pivot and match takes more time than using match along, hmm xP